# Magento: Supporting Configurable Products in Bundled Products

Tags: magento

Using the newest Magento, 1.8, I'm looking to support configurable products as members of bundled products.  This isn't treated out of the box.

It's clear that I'll need to start in the config XML, with this:

```
   <catalog>    
     <product>
       <type>
          <bundle>
            <allowed_selection_types>
              <configurable/>
            ...
```

The question is - where else am I going to have to extend the core code once bundles can include configurable products?   I'm looking for where the default code will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this need with a 3rd party module.
http://shop.wizkunde.nl/configurable-bundle.html